# Asymptotics of a convoluted sum involving $r^{-\alpha}$

Tags: inequality, summation, asymptotics

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be real constants satisfying $0<\alpha\leq \beta$, and let $R>1$ be an integer. Prove that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:lemma_convolution}
  \sum^{R-1}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r^\beta (R-r)^\alpha }\asymp\begin{cases}%\frac{1}{(R-r)^\alpha}\frac{1}{r^\beta}(R-r)^{-\alpha}r^{-\beta}
   R^{-\alpha},&\text{ if } \beta>1,\\%\frac{1}{R^\alpha}
   R^{-\alpha}\ln R,&\text{ if }\beta=1,\\%\frac{\ln R}{R^\alpha}
   R^{1-\alpha-\beta},&\text{ if } \beta<1,%\frac{1}{R^{\alpha+\beta-1}}
  \end{cases}
 \end{equation}
where the notation $f(R)\asymp g(R)$ means that there exist positive constants $c_1,c_2$ independent of $R$ such that  $c_1 g(R)\leq f(R)\leq c_2 g(R)$ for all $R\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.

[Note: I believe this is correct as I've verified it using mathematica, but I cannot prove it.]

Comment: $f(R)\sim g(R)$ means something else. You want $f(R)\asymp g(R)$.

Comment: Why not to look at the corresponding integral ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici But then, they'd get the constants, too! ;) And they don't seem to be interested in those.

Comment: @wasn'tme. It was just an idea since the integral is so simple.

Comment: @wasn'tme OK thanks. I've updated the symbol.